# Isotopic diffeomorphisms of the sphere

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Assume that $f:\mathbb{S}^n\to\mathbb{S}^n$ is a diffeomorphism and assume that there is an orientation preserving diffeomorphism $F:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that $F|_{\mathbb{S}^n}=f$. As far as I know it is well known that this implies that $f$ is isotopic to the identity $\operatorname{id}:\mathbb{S}^n\to\mathbb{S}^n$ though diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{S}^n$.

While it can easily be proved that $f$ is isotopic to $\operatorname{id}:\mathbb{S}^n\to\mathbb{S}^n$ through embeddings of $\mathbb{S}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, I do not see how to turn these embedings into isotopy of diffeomorphisms of the sphere. **Can someone explain it to me or give a reference?**

I also know that in general if $\mathbb{S}^n$ is replaced by other manifolds, then the answer is negative, see [Easiest example where pseudo-isotopy fails to be the same as isotopy?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/249398/121665)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is Cerf's pseudoisotopy-implies-isotopy theorem.

Cerf's result is true in high dimensions, while it's independently known in a low-dimensional range.  In dimension $2$ it goes back to the [Earle–Eells result](https://community.ams.org/journals/bull/1967-73-04/S0002-9904-1967-11746-4/S0002-9904-1967-11746-4.pdf) that $\pi_0\, \hbox{Diff}(S^2)$ has precisely two components, and in dimension $3$ it is the analogous theorem of Cerf.  But I think it's an open problem for $n=4$.

Jean Cerf (1970), [La stratification naturelle des espaces de fonctions différentiables réelles et le théorème de la pseudo-isotopie](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/cerf2.pdf), Inst. Hautes. Etudes Sci Publ. Math 39:5–173.

Comment: In dimension 2 the result is older than the Earle-Eells paper which was published in 1969 and which focuses on surfaces of higher genus. There is a paper by Smale in the 1959 AMS Proceedings that proves the stronger result that Diff$(S^2)$ deformation retracts onto $O(2)$.  For the $\pi_0$ statement Smale cites an announcement by Munkres in the 1958 AMS Notices.

Comment: @AllenHatcher thanks, I was drifting to the general pseudoisotopy vs. isotopy question for surfaces.  I suppose I should have added, I believe it goes back to Dehn in dimension 2 that homotopy implies isotopy for orientable surfaces.